# How to get more result than default ten results from API in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have an simple express app. I want to get twenty results from API at each time. This is API http://www.omdbapi.com/ that i use. Whenever i make the call each time, i get ten results. How do i get twenty results for each call efficiently? This is my code:

```
exports.getMovieFromApi = async (req, res) => {

  const response = await axios.get(
    http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${process.env.API_KEY}&s=${req.query.s}&page=${req.query.page}
  );
 
  res.status(200).json({
    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)),
  });
};
```

Comment: Check the api documentation to see if they allow getting more than 10 results.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to specify the count. You have to call it twice, first with `page=1` then with `page=2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a parameter for page size. I can see that they have a n open ticket: https://github.com/omdbapi/OMDb-API/issues/221